# Why \ProcessPgfOptions from "pgfopts" parses not only the options of my package?

Tags: pgfopts

This is my `foo.sty` package:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{foo}
\usepackage{pgfopts}
\pgfkeys{
  /foo/.cd,
  anonymous/.store in=\fooanon,
}
\ProcessPgfOptions{/foo}
\endinput
```

This is the document:

```
\documentclass[anonymous]{acmart}
\usepackage{./foo}
\begin{document}
\ifdefined\fooanon YES \else NO \fi
\end{document}
```

It prints `YES`, while I didn't provide the `anonymous` option to my package. Somehow it took it from the list of options I provided to the `acmart` class. Why and how to get rid of this "side effect"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like the standard `\ProcessOptions` command, `\ProcessPgfOptions` treats the optional argument to `\documentclass` as containing global options. It therefore examines those as well as package-specific ones. (This is the way for example `draft` is propagated from the global option list to `graphics`, etc.) If you want to examine only the list explicitly given for the package, use `\ProcessPgfPackageOptions`.